# How to Remove Webbrowser Without Uninstalling Unity Webapps?

Tags: unity, apt, uninstall, webapps

I want to save disk space by removing unwanted applications such as webbrowser(I use firefox). however, after sudo apt-get uninstalling or purging I can't open unity tweak tool, and by reinstalling web app services I get browser again. Is there anything I can do to remove browser?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything I can do to remove browser?

To remove the Ubuntu Web Browser, I opened a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then typed:

```
htop
```

Then hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to search. I searched for `browser` and found `webbrowser-app`, so I uninstalled it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove webbrowser-app
```

Comment: where to write htop?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan I've updated the answer.

Comment: does not answer the question which is how to remove webbrowser-app without removing things like the unity tweak tool which depends on webbrowser-app.

Comment: Hey guys, did you know that answers that don't directly answer the question can still be useful for people searching for a solution to a related problem? This is why the answer has been upvoted: because it was still useful. I upvote such answers often too, because they are useful. If you have an answer to the question, feel free to post it. Otherwise, I became aware that the answer doesn't solve the original question when bluppfisk left a comment back in 2018.